# How to use a list of layers in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The below code throws me an error "AttributeError: can't set attribute". I think this is because I am trying to put TensorFlow layers into an ordinary list.

Does anyone know how I can get around this and be able to create a list of layers? I don't want to use Sequential because it is less flexible.

In PyTorch they have ModuleLists which you can use instead of a list, is there an equivalent in TensorFlow I can use?

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.layers = self.create_layers()

  def create_layers(self):    
    layers = [Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), Flatten(), 
              Dense(128, activation='relu'), Dense(10, activation='softmax')]
    return layers

  def call(self, x):
    for layer in self.layers:
      x = layer(x)
    return x

model = MyModel()
```

[full problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTZka.png)

Answer (score 4):

`layers` is a reserved name for the layers of the model. Consider using another attribute for the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.layers_custom = self.create_layers()

  def create_layers(self):    
    layers = [Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), Flatten(), 
              Dense(128, activation='relu'), Dense(10, activation='softmax')]
    return layers

  def call(self, x):
    for layer in self.layers_custom:
      x = layer(x)
    return x

model = MyModel()
print(model.layers)
print(model.layers_custom)
```

Comment: Does this mean that TF inspects regular lists in search of nested modules? What If I tried to create a module dict?

Comment: I did not get what you meant

Comment: What I mean is, for instance, if I am ever to save/load a model with a list (or dict) of layers, will those layers be saved and loaded transparently (without any need for custom functions)?

Comment: tensorflow allows to save and load models; does it not cover what you want ? If you don't have custom layers, you won't need custom functions

Answer (score 1):

Just see this example in tf2.0's tutorial about how to make a list of layers
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix